# How to check value of parameters of RESTful controller's action

Tags: laravel

I use the **Larvel 4.1**

If I use routes for every action I can check parameters value into route like here

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

But I don't understand how to check this value when I define a route for a RESTful controller

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

Do I check parameters directly into controller's action or there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, looks like this is not the way Route::controller() works, but if you do

```
Route::pattern('one', '[0-9]+');
```

It will work. Because this is how Laravel create controller routes parameters:

```
GET|HEAD myactions/id/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}
```

The problem is that you cannot filter those parameters this way because they may appear in actions of different controllers. So you probably will have to create some of those routes manually:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Which, in my opinion is better than use a generic Route::controller() or Route::resource(). And in Phil Sturgeon's opinion too, as you can see in his article: http://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil

Comment: I was tried to do it, unfortunately this has not helped.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this won't work with named parameters, check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

So, I actually use separated routes for each action this manner

```
Route::pattern('one', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile');
```

I simple was hoped do it in more short way.